# Why can't I run DDLC?

Tags: linux, games

Im trying to run DDLC and I made sure I have permission to run everything, and when I run it here is my traceback

```
    I'm sorry, but an uncaught exception occurred.

While running game code:
  File "renpy/common/00start.rpy", line 188, in script call
    call _gl_test
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 361, in script
    $ __gl_test()
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 361, in <module>
    $ __gl_test()
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 287, in _m1_00gltest__gl_test
    _gl_performance_test()
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 304, in _gl_performance_test
    ui.interact(suppress_underlay=True, suppress_overlay=True)
error: Failed loading libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

-- Full Traceback ------------------------------------------------------------

Full traceback:
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/bootstrap.py", line 295, in bootstrap
    renpy.main.main()
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/main.py", line 487, in main
    run(restart)
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/main.py", line 147, in run
    renpy.execution.run_context(True)
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/execution.py", line 761, in run_context
    context.run()
  File "renpy/common/00start.rpy", line 188, in script call
    call _gl_test
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 361, in script
    $ __gl_test()
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/ast.py", line 814, in execute
    renpy.python.py_exec_bytecode(self.code.bytecode, self.hide, store=self.store)
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/python.py", line 1719, in py_exec_bytecode
    exec bytecode in globals, locals
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 361, in <module>
    $ __gl_test()
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 287, in _m1_00gltest__gl_test
    _gl_performance_test()
  File "renpy/common/00gltest.rpy", line 304, in _gl_performance_test
    ui.interact(suppress_underlay=True, suppress_overlay=True)
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/ui.py", line 285, in interact
    rv = renpy.game.interface.interact(roll_forward=roll_forward, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/display/core.py", line 2494, in interact
    self.start()
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/display/core.py", line 1686, in start
    self.set_mode()
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/display/core.py", line 1916, in set_mode
    if draw.set_mode(virtual_size, physical_size, fullscreen):
  File "/home/vinnyviele6/DDLC-1.1.1-pc/renpy/display/swdraw.py", line 759, in set_mode
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((scaled_width, scaled_height), fsflag, 32)
  File "src/pygame_sdl2/display.pyx", line 438, in pygame_sdl2.display.set_mode (gen/pygame_sdl2.display.c:6434)
  File "src/pygame_sdl2/display.pyx", line 168, in pygame_sdl2.display.Window.__init__ (gen/pygame_sdl2.display.c:2942)
error: Failed loading libGL.so.1: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Linux-4.19.44-04937-gd773af751792-x86_64-with-debian-9.9
Ren'Py 6.99.12.4.2187
Doki Doki Literature Club! 1.1.1
```

So, I think it is because I don't have libGL.so.1, but this has ran on my computer before. Is there something I am missing?

NOTE: I am using a Crostini on my Chromebook. It is in developer mode and Crouton takes up all of my storage and I can't get a USB

Comment: it's definitely because you don't have the libGL.so.1 it was linked against, possibly because of a package upgrade or removal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do have libGL.so.1 on your computer, uninstall and reinstall. I had this same error happen to me, and I fixed it by doing this